# Why not "get" a friend?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

It is only natural you would want to **have** a friend if you moved to a different country for some reason and therefore you don't have any local friend there.

As I was looking the other day into the usage of verbs that usually go together with the very popular word "friend," I learned, unexpectedly, English speakers hardly say, "**get** a friend," when they commonly say, "**find** a friend," which is very familiar to me too.

Even more interestingly and confusingly, they often talk about "**getting**" a girlfriend or boyfriend as well as "**finding**"a girlfriend or boyfriend.

Why not "**get**" a friend to mean the same as "**find**" a friend? I'm seriously curious if my understanding is correct.

Comment: The word "get" seems to me too mundane and banal for something as personal as finding a friend. It is the kind of word which is used for everyday things like "I must go to the shop and ***get*** some potatoes". If friends were had off the shelf then "get" might be appropriate. I might use it for "friend" if speaking very casually, but mostly I prefer a word like "find", which also implies selectivity. Choosing a fried is a more important decision than acquiring a good fitting pair of shoes.

Comment: I guess James Taylor's song, "You've Got a Friend (in Me)," is a different construction?

Comment: I miss the word "make" here.

Comment: Yes, that uses the word "got" in a different sense, and it is unnecessary. It would mean exactly the same to say "you have a friend in me"

Comment: @MrLister Good point. I wish I had thought of that when writing my comment.

Comment: WS2: I like your paraphrase. It's helpful. MrLister: Are you by any chance suggesting the phrase "make friends"? If so, my understanding is you can only say either "make FRIENDS with~" or "make A FREIND of~." Correct me if I'm mistaken

Comment: @ChoeGuevara You can "make new friends" without "with".

Comment: Just for completeness, you can also "make somebody with a friend" (that somebody is typically young).

Answer (score 2):

One may *get a friend*

> I'm going to *get a friend* to help me

but, that person must first be a friend.

To have a friend, one might

> make a friend [MACMILLAN DICTIONARY](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/make-friends)

or

> find a friend

*Make a friend* seems to be a more established idiom in English   than *finding a friend* (that is for the process of becoming friends with somebody).  I cannot find a authority offering a definition of *finding a friend.*

One might look for, or by chance, discover one who becomes a friend, and that can be *finding a friend*. Still, though, in *finding a friend* one is *making a friend*.

The accepted definition of *get* [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/get) might cause one to think a friend could be *got* as well as *made*.  English speakers, for whatever reason, seem not to think of *getting* a friend, rather they think of *making* one

Comment: It boggles my mind that absolutely nobody on this page has ever [heard of the Backstreet Boys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=npghk4uqkCs).

Answer (score -1):

I should say we 'make' friends, rather than 'get' them, which implies something one-sided, and not very friendly at all!

Comment: I agree. But you don't say "make a girlfriend or boyfriend" whereas it is perfectly fine to say "find a girlfriend or boyfriend", do you?

Comment: @ChoeGuevara Boy/girlfriends are gotten, friends are made, and both can be found. This is just how the language is.

Comment: No, but I can't think of any circumstance when I would say 'find' a boy/girlfriend either.  ('I'm going to find a boy/girlfriend...'?)  I can see that I may 'meet' or 'have' a boy/girlfriend, but not 'find'.   Perhaps this is an English/American difference, the English don't use 'gotten' at all, even 'got' is not in an English dictionary, under 'got' is a referral to 'get'.